# √7 is irrational. how to prove it

Tags: proof-writing

(√7) is (IR) irrational Number. How to prove it√7 .

Firstly I tried a/b =√7 and 
a^2 /b^2 =7 
7b^2=a^2 
And then I couldn't continue .
How I can Prove it ?

Comment: Do you know the classic proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrational? This proof is basically exactly the same (and you've started well).

Comment: Yes , I aggre with you . But when I prove it in √2 I look at odd and even number . But √7 different . I can't look odd or even . I have to tried new way . Right?

Comment: "I look at odd and even number ..... I can't look odd or even " Even means divisible by two.  So what?  Divisible by $7$ just as legitimate a concept.  $7$ divides evenly into $a^2$ so .....

Comment: ....But this does assume that Euclids lemma that if prime number $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.  Don't know if you have proven that.

Comment: I understand thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sqrt{7} = a/b$, where $a/b$ is in lowest terms, meaning $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.  Then, as you showed, $7b^2 = a^2$.  This forces $7 \mid a^2$, which, since $7$ is prime forces $7 \mid a$.  But then $7^2$ divides $a^2$, so $7^2$ divides $7b^2$, forcing $7 \mid b^2$, forcing $7 \mid b$.  Now we have shown $7 \mid a$ and $7 \mid b$, which contradicts our assumption that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.  By contradiction, $\sqrt{7}$ is not rational.

Answer (score 0):

Again, suppose that $\sqrt 7=a/b$ in lowest terms. Then $a^2=7b^2$.
Modulo $5$ the only possibilities for $a^2$ are $a^2\equiv0$, $1$ or $4\pmod5$.
Likewise, $7b^2\equiv0$, $2$ or $3\pmod5$. Therefore $a^2\equiv 7b^2\equiv0\pmod 5$ which is only possible if $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $5$. This contradicts
$a/b$ being in lowest terms.